# CSS Checkboxes Side By Side

Tags: html, css

I'm hoping someone can help me get these two checkboxes with text side by side instead of top / bottom.

Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/j8y1x7q9/

```
    <div class="checkbox-wrapper-33">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input class="checkbox__trigger visuallyhidden" name="WAV" type="checkbox" checked />
    <span class="checkbox__symbol">
      <svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon-checkbox" width="28px" height="28px" viewBox="0 0 28 28" version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M4 14l8 7L24 7"></path>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <p class="checkbox__textwrapper">WAV</p>
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input class="checkbox__trigger visuallyhidden" name="MP3" type="checkbox" />
    <span class="checkbox__symbol">
      <svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon-checkbox" width="28px" height="28px" viewBox="0 0 28 28" version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M4 14l8 7L24 7"></path>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <p class="checkbox__textwrapper">MP3</p>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `flex` box in the parent component `.checkbox-wrapper-33`

Check this example:

```
.checkbox-wrapper-33 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
}
```

This would be your output after adding flexbox in your code:

```css
.checkbox-wrapper-33 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
}

.checkbox-wrapper-33 {
  --s-xsmall: 0.625em;
  --s-small: 1.2em;
  --border-width: 1px;
  --c-primary: #3a3a3c;
  --c-primary-20-percent-opacity: rgb(55 55 55 / 20%);
  --c-primary-10-percent-opacity: rgb(55 55 55 / 10%);
  --t-base: 0.4s;
  --t-fast: 0.2s;
  --e-in: ease-in;
  --e-out: cubic-bezier(.11, .29, .18, .98);
}

.checkbox-wrapper-33 .visuallyhidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}

.checkbox-wrapper-33 .checkbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.checkbox-wrapper-33 .checkbox+.checkbox {
  margin-left: var(--s-small);
}

.checkbox-wrapper-33 .checkbox__symbol {
  display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: calc(var(--s-small) * 0.7);
  border: var(--border-width) solid var(--c-primary);
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0.1em;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  transition: box-shadow var(--t-base) var(--e-out), background-color var(--t-base);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 var(--c-primary-10-percent-opacity);
}

.checkbox-wrapper-33 .checkbox__symbol:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
  width: 0.25em;
  height: 0.25em;
  background-color: var(--c-primary-20-percent-opacity);
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 3em;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.checkbox-wrapper-33 .checkbox .icon-checkbox {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin: auto;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke: currentColor;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  color: var(--c-primary);
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkbox-wrapper-33 .checkbox .icon-checkbox path {
  transition: stroke-dashoffset var(--t-fast) var(--e-in);
  stroke-dasharray: 30px, 31px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 31px;
}

.checkbox-wrapper-33 .checkbox__textwrapper {
  margin: 0;
}

.checkbox-wrapper-33 .checkbox__trigger:checked+.checkbox__symbol:after {
  -webkit-animation: ripple-33 1.5s var(--e-out);
  animation: ripple-33 1.5s var(--e-out);
}

.checkbox-wrapper-33 .checkbox__trigger:checked+.checkbox__symbol .icon-checkbox path {
  transition: stroke-dashoffset var(--t-base) var(--e-out);
  stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
}

.checkbox-wrapper-33 .checkbox__trigger:focus+.checkbox__symbol {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25em var(--c-primary-20-percent-opacity);
}

@-webkit-keyframes ripple-33 {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(20);
  }
}

@keyframes ripple-33 {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(20);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-wrapper-33">
  <label class="checkbox">
        <input class="checkbox__trigger visuallyhidden" name="WAV" type="checkbox" checked />
        <span class="checkbox__symbol">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon-checkbox" width="28px" height="28px" viewBox="0 0 28 28" version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M4 14l8 7L24 7"></path>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <p class="checkbox__textwrapper">WAV</p>
      </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
        <input class="checkbox__trigger visuallyhidden" name="MP3" type="checkbox" />
        <span class="checkbox__symbol">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon-checkbox" width="28px" height="28px" viewBox="0 0 28 28" version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M4 14l8 7L24 7"></path>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <p class="checkbox__textwrapper">MP3</p>
      </label>
</div>
```

Comment: happy learning!